# I need a function like countif in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, count

I have this table like this

```
Status    Last_update_time
4      | 2/2/2021, 11:03
5      | 2/2/2021, 12:04
4      | 24/2/2021, 12:36
4      | 20/2/2021, 17:33
5      | 13/2/2021, 10:57
```

I already write a SQL like this

```
Select date_trunc('week', CAST(kyc.last_update_time as timestamp )) AS "week",
       Count(status)
From KYC
Where kyc.status = 4 
  and (kyc.last_update_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '3 week') 
       and kyc.last_update_time < date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
Group by 1
```

So it will count for me all status 4 for each week in last 3 week

But now I want to change that I can count 4 and 5. And when I visualization, I will have 2 columns, 1 for status 4, 1 for status 5

My expected output SQL like this

```
Select date_trunc('week', CAST(kyc.last_update_time as timestamp )) AS "week",
       Count(if(kyc.status = 4,kyc.used_id,null) as XTTC
       Count(if(kyc.status = 5,kyc.used_id,null) as XTTB
From KYC 

Where (kyc.last_update_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '3 week') 
       and kyc.last_update_time < date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
Group by 1
```

Is there any function like countif in excel that can help me with this

Thank you

Comment: I don't see an actual problem statement here.  Please add one.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output.

Comment: You can do a "count if" using `count(...) filter (where ...)`

Comment: i edited, please check and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name suggests you can use conditional [aggregation with filter](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) as a very capable alternative of `countif` in order to achieve this.

```sql
select date_trunc('week', last_update_time::timestamp) as "week", 
       count(*) filter (where status = 4) as "XTTC",
       count(*) filter (where status = 5) as "XTTB"
from kyc
where last_update_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '3 weeks') 
  and last_update_time <  date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
group by 1;
```

Comment: I already try this but it said column used_id doesn't exist. Why?. Because in table have this column

Comment: Can you pls. share your table DDL?

Comment: Or easier, just replace `count(used_id)` with `count(*)`. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Yeah, your new edit is working, thank you.